# How to show/hide components in React using Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Link to the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tavares-convert-to-hooks-flxdf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to see what I mean.

When you click the View Profile button on a player, the player's profile currently loads below the cards. This is because the Switch / Router statement is directly below the cards, so the components will load there.

However, what I want is when someone clicks on a player's "View Profile" button, it loads up the detailed profile and that's it. It currently does navigate to the right routes, but those routes I just want the detailed profile. I don't want it to load up the card overviews of all three players.

App.js (removed the styled components to keep concise):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Row, Col, Card } from "reactstrap";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import Intro from "./components/Intro";
import Tavares from "./components/Tavares";
import Matthews from "./components/Matthews";
import Marner from "./components/Marner";

import TavaresImg from "./img/tavares.jpg";
import MatthewsImg from "./img/matthews.jpg";
import MarnerImg from "./img/marner.jpg";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  // Set initial state for data
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    tavares: [],
    matthews: [],
    marner: [],
    tavaresFull: [],
    matthewsFull: [],
    marnerFull: []
  });

  // Fetch data
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      // Grab all players API's
      let tavares =
        "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8475166?expand=person.stats&stats=yearByYear,careerRegularSeason&expand=stats.team&site=en_nhlCA";
      let matthews =
        "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8479318?expand=person.stats&stats=yearByYear,careerRegularSeason&expand=stats.team&site=en_nhlCA";
      let marner =
        "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8478483?expand=person.stats&stats=yearByYear,careerRegularSeason&expand=stats.team&site=en_nhlCA";
      // Axios to get all api's
      axios
        .all([axios.get(tavares), axios.get(matthews), axios.get(marner)])
        .then(
          axios.spread((tavares, matthews, marner) => {
            console.log(tavares.data.people[0].stats[1].splits[0].stat);
            setData({
              tavares: [tavares.data.people[0]],
              matthews: [matthews.data.people[0]],
              marner: [marner.data.people[0]],
              tavaresFull: [tavares.data.people[0].stats[1].splits[0].stat],
              matthewsFull: [matthews.data.people[0].stats[1].splits[0].stat],
              marnerFull: [marner.data.people[0].stats[1].splits[0].stat]
            });
          })
        );
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <Intro
          main="Maple Leafs API"
          text="Built with React, React Hooks, Styled Components and Axios
                consuming the NHL's REST API."
        />
        <Flex>
          <Container>
            <RowWrap>
              <Row>
                <Col lg="4">
                  <Image>
                    <img src={TavaresImg} alt="Tavares" />
                  </Image>
                </Col>
                <Col lg="8">
                  <CardBody>
                    {data.tavares.map(item => (
                      <>
                        <Title>
                          <h1>{item.fullName}</h1>
                        </Title>
                        <Number>{item.primaryNumber}</Number>
                        <p>{item.primaryPosition.name}</p>
                      </>
                    ))}
                    <ButtonLink>
                      <Link to="/tavares">
                        <button>View Profile</button>
                      </Link>
                    </ButtonLink>
                  </CardBody>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </RowWrap>
            <RowWrap>
              <Row>
                <Col lg="4">
                  <Image>
                    <img src={MatthewsImg} alt="Matthews" />
                  </Image>
                </Col>
                <Col lg="8">
                  <CardBody>
                    {data.matthews.map(item => (
                      <>
                        <Title>
                          <h1>{item.fullName}</h1>
                        </Title>
                        <Number>{item.primaryNumber}</Number>
                        <p>{item.primaryPosition.name}</p>
                      </>
                    ))}
                    <ButtonLink>
                      <Link to="/matthews">
                        <button>View Profile</button>
                      </Link>
                    </ButtonLink>
                  </CardBody>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </RowWrap>
            <RowWrap>
              <Row>
                <Col lg="4">
                  <Image>
                    <img src={MarnerImg} alt="Marner" />
                  </Image>
                </Col>
                <Col lg="8">
                  <CardBody>
                    {data.marner.map(item => (
                      <>
                        <Title>
                          <h1>{item.fullName}</h1>
                        </Title>
                        <Number>{item.primaryNumber}</Number>
                        <p>{item.primaryPosition.name}</p>
                      </>
                    ))}
                    <ButtonLink>
                      <Link to="/marner">
                        <button>View Profile</button>
                      </Link>
                    </ButtonLink>
                  </CardBody>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </RowWrap>
          </Container>
        </Flex>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="12">
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/tavares"
                  component={() => (
                    <Tavares data={data.tavares} dataFull={data.tavaresFull} />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/matthews"
                  component={() => (
                    <Matthews
                      data={data.matthews}
                      dataFull={data.matthewsFull}
                    />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/marner"
                  component={() => (
                    <Marner data={data.marner} dataFull={data.marnerFull} />
                  )}
                />
              </Switch>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Here is your solution https://codesandbox.io/s/tavares-convert-to-hooks-rcfk8

Comment: As @vinayakshahdeo shared, just create a master/list route that contains the cards with links to the detail routes.

Comment: @vinayakshahdeo, the link throws errors?

Comment: nope It would not throw error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your common component i.e the dashboard page is an outside switch so each time it has to render. For you to achieve this make another Dashboard component and link it to "/" route.  [Check here and optimise](https://codesandbox.io/s/tavares-convert-to-hooks-rcfk8)